# Rails | figaro heroku:set "Could not find command"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, heroku, rails-geocoder, figaro-ruby

I'm using two API : Cloudinary and Google Maps Geocoding API, both works on development with no problems. 
But on prod, Google Maps doesn't work because "Google Maps API warning: NoApiKeys".

```
heroku config:set GOOGLE_API_SERVER_KEY=AIza*****************************4
```

Works fine, I find both of my API's keys on my heroku's dashboard, but :

```
figaro heroku:set -e production
Could not find command "heroku:set"
```

Same with :

```
figaro heroku:set
Could not find command "heroku:set"
```

I suppose my problem is with the gem figaro.
My gemfile :

```
#figaro
gem 'figaro', '~> 1.1', '>= 1.1.1'
```

Application.yml

```
# Add configuration values here, as shown below.
#
# pusher_app_id: "2954"
# pusher_key: 7381a978f7dd7f9a1117
# pusher_secret: abdc3b896a0ffb85d373
# stripe_api_key: sk_test_2J0l093xOyW72XUYJHE4Dv2r
# stripe_publishable_key: pk_test_ro9jV5SNwGb1yYlQfzG17LHK
#
# production:
#   stripe_api_key: sk_live_EeHnL644i6zo4Iyq4v1KdV9H
#   stripe_publishable_key: pk_live_9lcthxpSIHbGwmdO941O1XVU

CLOUDINARY_URL: "cloudinary://6714********************************t"
GOOGLE_API_SERVER_KEY: "AIz***********************************4"
```

When I type :

```
bundle exec figaro heroku:set
```

I have everythings good (I guess):

```
Setting CLOUDINARY_URL, GOOGLE_API_SERVER_KEY and restarting ⬢ coin-de-paris... done, v27
CLOUDINARY_URL:        cloudinary://671**********************st
GOOGLE_API_SERVER_KEY: AI**********************4
```

I'm new in the dev world, so sorry if the answer is easy :) 
Thanks for your time !

***EDIT***: 
I tried few versions of figaro like :

```
gem 'figaro', '~> 1.1', '>= 1.1.1'
gem 'figaro', github: 'sealocal/figaro'
gem 'figaro', '>= 1.0.0.rc1'
gem 'figaro'
```

Then :

```
bundle install
bundle binstubs figaro
figaro install
spring stop
```

but still when I run :

```
figaro heroku:set -e production
```

and

```
figaro heroku:set
```

I have :

```
Could not find command "heroku:set".
```

Versions:

```
ruby '2.3.5'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.4'
```

Comment: which version are you using for ruby, rails and figaro ?

Comment: Gemfile : 
ruby '2.3.5'
gem 'figaro', '~> 1.1', '>= 1.1.1'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.4'

Comment: Can you try this once gem 'figaro', github: 'sealocal/figaro' ?

Comment: @sam I tried, but it's still doesn't work

Comment: figaro heroku:set -e production try this

Comment: Yes this is the command I tried and unfortunately, this command doesn't work

Comment: gem 'figaro', '>= 1.0.0.rc1', This is confirmed solution please try it properly. This version has solved that issue. Then try figaro heroku:set -e production.

Comment: it doesn't work. I tried this solution too. 
Just for to be clear, I replace the gemfile, then 'bundle', then figaro heroku:set -e production' ? I didn't forget anything ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found, it was a problem with my key. I generated an other one in google console and now it's fine.